# return the 5 latest records from a stream in ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm using the latest Version of ksqldb and fired a http2 post request (with the INSOMNIA testing tool) against the `/query-stream` service. This script works fine and returns the schema and 5 records. (my stream is defined in JSON not AVRO)

```
{
    "sql": "SELECT botid, token, pair, price FROM QS EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 5;",
    "properties": {
        "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    }
}
```

One question from my http2 tests with Insomnia,ksqldb REST API and the confluent control center (query):

1. If I don't apply the `LIMIT 5`, then no values are returned and the connection wheel keeps spinning and only new records are shown. My expectation is that it would return the latest 5 and return new records upon arrival. Why is LIMIT ignored when using `latest`?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The limit only applies to fresh events, or those at the beginning; it's not the most recent 5 messages unless the topic only has 5 messages total

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks. Yes that would cover with my observation. But how would you cover the use case where you want to get the 5 latest records and keep the connection open (http2) for new records to come? e.g. a web page showing the latest 5 records (where as the oldest record is removed a new arrives).

Comment: I'd write custom logic for that within my app. I'm not sure it's possible with ksql

Comment: @OneCricketeer Which would result in transporting more data than you need. I'm not a big fan of that. But yes, a workaround for now. My reaction to it is that I changed the functionality a bit: I just ask for the records not older than a day. SELECT *  FROM SIGNALS where eventtime > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400000) EMIT CHANGES;